# Initially publishing a github package shows "Username must not be null!"

Tags: github, gradle

I am trying to publish a package on Github using the Gradle part in Android Studio. It is not my first one but I cannot find what the difference is to the previous ones and why I get this error.
I can successfully run the build step and the files are in the output folder. However, when I run the step "publish", I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:  
Execution failed for task  
':config_properties_reader_android:publishBarPublicationToGitHubPackagesRepository'.  
Failed to publish publication 'bar' to repository 'GitHubPackages'  
 -> Username must not be null!
```

The only difference I could find was that my module folder with the files to publish contains three instead of the usual two files:

Those two I would expect:

```
config_properties_reader_android/build/outputs/aar/config_properties_reader_android-debug.aar
config_properties_reader_android/build/outputs/aar/config_properties_reader_android-release.aar
```

And this one seems odd:

```
config_properties_reader_android/build/outputs/aar/configpropertiesreader-debug.aar
```

My gradle file looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'maven-publish'

def githubProperties = new Properties()
githubProperties.load(new FileInputStream(rootProject.file("github.properties")))

def getVersionName = { ->
    return "1.0.0"
}

def getArtificatId = { ->
    return "config_properties_reader_android"
}

publishing {
    publications {
        bar(MavenPublication) {g
            groupId 'com.MyGithubRepo'
            artifactId getArtificatId()
            version getVersionName()
            artifact("$buildDir/outputs/aar/${getArtificatId()}-release.aar")
        }
    }

    repositories {
        maven {
            name = "GitHubPackages"
            url = uri("https://maven.pkg.github.com/MyGithubRepo/ConfigPropertiesReader.Android")
            credentials {
                username = githubProperties['gpr.usr'] ?: System.getenv("GPR_USER")
                password = githubProperties['gpr.key'] ?: System.getenv("GPR_API_KEY")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And my github.properties file also contains the usual:

```
gpr.user=myUser
gpr.key=myKey
```

Could the third file in the ouput folder be the problem? I do not see how the username should have anything to do with it but I have no idea where to look in order to find the error.

Comment: Is your project part of a multi-project build? I was just wondering why you would use `rootProject.file("github.properties")`. Did you check whether the correct file is loaded using `println githubProperties['gpr.usr']`?

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for, a way to debug! Thanks! "gpr.usr" and "gpr.user" is not quite the same..

Answer (score 2):

Change gpr.user => gpr.usr

Also, use your git user-id in gpr.usr
and use git personal access token in gpr.key

i also have this issue this change solve mine problem

Answer (score 1):

check the below line and replace the username and password it will work

file name is `build.gradle`

```
maven {
     url "https://cardinalcommerceprod.jfrog.io/artifactory/android"
    credentials {
      username 'braintree_team_sdk'
      password 'AKCp8jQcoDy2hxSWhDAUQKXLDPDx6NYRkqrgFLRc3qDrayg6rrCbJpsKKyMwaykVL8FWusJpp'
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in github.properties file

gpr.usr=myUser

gpr.key=myKey